# purpose of なく in this sentence

Tags: particles

下の牛舎から上にいくまでの
道に落ちた堆肥をホウキなどで道の端にはくのではなくこれからは一輪車で集めて捨てるようにしてください

is the naku a form of nai, and does it mean the compost won't peel off the road? But from the rest of the sentence I get the feeling its different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the く form of ない. The pattern [Verb] のではなく means "It is not that [the subject] does [whatever the verb is], but . . .". More idiomatically "instead of doing [such-and such]", "rather than doing [so-and-so]".

So this means "Instead of sweeping any manure that falls onto the path up from the lower cowshed to the side of the path with a broom, in future please be sure to (ようにする - "make a point of") collect it up with a wheelbarrow and dispose of it [properly]"

The fact that the path is coming up from the lower cowshed suggests that the stuff being dropped is animal manure rather that compost.

I have a question: What is the  まで doing?

Comment: I believe the まで is simply rfering to the road leading form the lower cowshed to the upper cowshed only. That specific section of road. And your right it is cow manure, but mostly compost, since that is what they bed the cows with here.

Answer (score 2):

The part of interest here is ではなく which is the continuative form of ではない.
I find that AではなくB often translates reasonably as "B rather than A". So in this case

> Rather than sweeping the crap ... make sure you ...